# Ruby on Rails SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Olá, estou enfrentando um problema com SQLite3. Quando eu executo o código:

```
user = SystemUser.new(email: "marcos@example.com", password: "marcos123")
user.profile = Profile.new(first_name: "Marcos")
user.save
```

O Rails executa no SQLite:

```
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SystemUser Exists (2.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "system_users" WHERE "system_users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "marcos@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (7.1ms)  INSERT INTO "system_users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "marcos@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$Wl8mzOtFlD9RRCdAr38Ze.vYdrbrPRHkIEqutAsAyodQSDzihy35O"], ["created_at", "2017-11-12 23:27:23.270956"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-12 23:27:23.270956"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (5188.0ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("first_name", "created_at", "updated_at", "system_user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["first_name", "Marcos"], ["created_at", "2017-11-12 23:27:23.281227"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-12 23:27:23.281227"], ["system_user_id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (6.2ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "profiles" ("first_name", "created_at", "updated_at", "system_user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        from (irb):3
```

Ele cria uma transação dentro de outra. Li que o SQLite bloqueia o arquivo durante uma transação. Procurei uma resolução mas não achei. Se alguém passou por isso e puder me ajudar ficarei muito agradecido.

Já testei com mysql e o código funciona

---

Uma solução encontrada:

O projeto se encontrava em Rails 5.1.4
Fiz o downgrade do projeto pro Rails 5.1.0, o erro persistiu. Depois criei um projeto em Rails 5.0.6, o problema sumiu. Então é isso, uma solução é usar o Rails 5.0.6

Aqui com 5.0.6

```
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (10.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["email", "marcos@example.com"], ["created_at", "2017-11-13 00:27:42.036072"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-13 00:27:42.036072"]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("first_name", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["first_name", "Marcos"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-11-13 00:27:42.122640"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-13 00:27:42.122640"]]
   (5.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuando o diário de bordo: O problema está na gem 'apartment'. Esse problema acontece nos modelos que estão no config.excluded_models